# crear un multi instalador de programas con chocolatey

Tags: cmd, powershell

Hay alguna manera de poder crear un multi instalador de programas a través de chocolatey, crear en un archivo .bat o .cmd donde al ejecutarce instale el chocolatey y seguido empiece a instalar una lista de programas antes creada, y que instale la ultima versión de cada uno. Que solo sea ejecutar el archivo y que se empiece a instalar todo solo.

Answer (score 0):

En lo personal, utilizo un script (al que le voy agregando mas software y configuraciones) para cada instalación que realizo en mi equipo. Lo siguiente es parte del script:

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole(`
    [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] “Administrator”)) {
    Write-Host “You do not have Administrator rights to run this script!`nPlease re-run this script as an Administrator!”
    Break
}

#Execution policy
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process -Force

#Install Chocolatey
iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex

#Install software from Chocolatey
choco install powershell -y
choco install google-chrome-x64 -y
choco install visualstudiocode -y
choco install vscode-powershell -y
choco install docker -y
choco install inkscape -y
choco install 7zip -y
choco install slack -y
choco install vlc -y
choco install wunderlist -y

#install git y revisar error de Chrome

#Remove all desktop shortcuts
Remove-Item C:\Users\*\Desktop\*lnk –Force
```

Esta podría ser una manera, ya que con Chocolatey siempre instalas la última versión.